# Sharing ANTLR grammars among unrelated projects

Tags: .net, antlr

I am looking for a way to manage dependencies between grammars in multiple .NET systems.

I have several .NET libraries that make use of application-specific languages:

- A library for computing expressions specified at run-time,
- A library for making queries to an application-specific database,
- A library for running multiple interdependent computations,
- A few other projects with their own little languages

Here is a diagram showing dependencies among my libraries and their lexer/parser combinations:

[image: Parser Dependency]

Arrows show dependencies among various parts of my system:

1. Dependencies between a library and its grammar,
2. Dependencies among .NET modules as presented to our build system (MSBuild), and
3. Source-level dependencies among grammars through the `import` directive in the grammar file.

Dependencies of the first and the second kind (shown with blue arrows) are managed perfectly by the build system, and do not cause any problems for us. However, dependencies of the third type (red arrows) require the source code of the expression grammar to be available when compiling the query grammar. This kind of dependency is not directly supported by the build system, and it breaks an attempt to modularize the system.

I worked around the technicalities of this problem by copying the source files of the expression grammar to a shared location at the time of the build, so that the build of a dependent library could pick it up from there. However, the logic remains broken, because copying creates a hidden dependency of which the build system is not aware.

I am looking for a solution that lets the build system manage this source dependency, or eliminates it completely.

Comment: You are using ExpressionLexer/Parser.g as both a stand-alone grammars and grammars that are included via Antlr "import". What I would do here is to place the Expression*.g grammars in Expression/ and set up a Project for that. Then, in two additional C# projects, ComputingEngine/ and QueryLibrary/, add links to the grammars in Expression/. In Expression/ run Antlr on the two grammars. In ComputingEngine/, run Antlr on ComputingEngineLexer/Parser.g. In QueryLibrary/, run Antlr on QueryLexer/Parser.g. You'll have to add references from ComputeEngine to QueryLibrary, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all grammars in a separate project (for example a "parsers" library) that provides base parsing functionality for the other libs/engines:

```
(ExpressionParser, QueryParser, ComputingEngineParser) <--- [Parsers.DLL]

[Parsers.DLL] <--- [ExpressionLibrary.DLL]
              <--- [QueryLibrary.DLL]
              <--- [ComputingEngine.EXE]
```